# What happens if a firebase url doesnot exist and we try to add a listener to it?

Tags: android, firebase

I am developing an application in which I ask the user to enter the city and state name and return certain location in that place. But the problem is that if the specified state or city doesn't exist in my Firebase then my Progress Dialog,which I am supposed to dismiss when the listener has triggered, keeps moving and no action is triggered further.

Here is that portion of my code:

//state = get from user
//city = get from user

```
mapProgress.show();
```

firebase.child("markers").child(state).child(city).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                                mapProgress.dismiss();

if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                        //do something
                            }
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No data found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                            mapProgress.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The methods in a `ChildEventListener` are called when a child is added, changed, removed or moved. On an empty location, none of these events happen, so none of the methods are called.

A `ValueEventListener` will be called with an empty value if no value exists at a location. So if you also call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`, you can detect that the location has no value:

```
Firebase cityRef = firebase.child("markers").child(state).child(city);
cityRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.getValue() == null) {
            System.out.println("No data exists for "+city);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

If you want to handle the children in the same call, you can just loop over them in `onDataChange()`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.getValue() == null) {
        System.out.println("No data exists for "+city);
    }
    else {
        for (DataSnapshot citySnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            // Do something with citySnapshot.getValue()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think using value event listeners will give me all data at a time so delay will be more and hence adding child one by one will at least provide some data so that the user can view something.Just like slow image loading in shopping application, they keep user engaged while other images are loading.How can i achieve that?

Comment: The network traffic is exactly the same between both approaches.