# Firebase ValueEventListener return non existing key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this standard Firebase call:

```
ref.child("user/toys/-K2873267832")
   .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot ) {
         if (dataSnapshot != null) {
           // wow the Data at Firebase database does not exist
         }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the ref `"user/toys/-K2873267832"` does not exist. When I delete the key at console.firebase.google.com the `dataSnapshot` should not have data right. Even the key `user/toys` is deleted.

I have been working on this project for month and have many `ValueEventListener` in a complex database. This is something I never seen before.

What can cause this to happen?

Comment: So dataSnapshot is not equal to null?

Comment: exactly, The  DataSnapshot { key =-K2873267832, value = null }

Comment: See the answer posted; you get a value for that location, but that's expected. It's also expected that it will not have a value. If you're trying to check for existence at a location, this is how you'd do it - use a value event listener and then see if the data is null.

You can also do the call on the parent node and use the `hasChild` method to see if it exists as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397205/google-firebase-check-if-child-exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460779/what-happens-if-a-firebase-url-doesnot-exist-and-we-try-to-add-a-listener-to-it) :

> A ValueEventListener will be called with an empty value if no value
>   exists at a location. So if you also call
>   addListenerForSingleValueEvent(), you can detect that the location has
>   no value.

then he says that `dataSnapshot.getValue()` should equal `null`. So while a valid dataSnapshot will be returned, the value at that snapshot will be null.

Comment: So there is never a situation where dataSnapshot is null?